# Ubuntu 18.04 autostart script with gdm

Tags: gnome, 18.04, gdm

How can I start a program/script as **root** as soon as GDM starts. I need the said program/script to start even before the user has logged in. It needs to start as soon as the GDM login screen shows up.

I know that putting something in `/etc/xdg/autostart` starts the program/script on user login. Where do I put my script to have it start before user login?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Putting the `.desktop` file under `/usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart/` will start the program/script when gdm loads the login screen (before actual user login).

But this has some strings attached, for instance, `dconf-service` isn't loaded until the user logs in so `libdconf` won't be able to read anything. This holds true even after the user logs in since `dconf-service` loads under the logged in session.